# How can I disable the guest account on OSX Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, user-accounts, macbook, guest-account

I have 'disabled' the guest account on my macbook pro running Lion via System Preferences > Users & Groups.

[image: Guest Account Disabled]

However the guest account still seems to appear as an option to login at start up and when switching users.

I have never used the guest account for anything, and I have tried a system restore but the guest user has returned as before. How can I get rid of it?

Thanks.

edit: I also just enabled and disabled the account again - but the guest option still appears at startup offering a safari only restart for a guest user.

Comment: Not sure why people are down voting this question, if there is anything that needs improving, please comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check *Disable restarting to Safari when screen is locked* in *System Preferences » Security & Privacy » General*. This option controls whether Safari Mode is available when starting the computer. It's not an actual (temporary) user account, so the user accounts preferences aren't having an effect.

[image: Screenshot of System Preferences]

Comment: Note that "Screen is locked" is an interesting sign of the iOS-ification of Mac OS X. There is no "locked screen" and "computer turned off" anymore: It's the same thing.